# Is there a better way to convert a WebControl that uses nested ITemplates to be used in Razor?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, web-controls

I'm converting old aspx/ascx pages to now use Razor and I've run into a WebControl that can't easily become a helper method or cshtml.

The WebControl has several nested ITemplate properties like this:

```cs
[ToolboxData("<{0}:LightBox runat=server></{0}:LightBox>")]
public class Lightbox : WebControl, INamingContainer
{
    [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
    public ITemplate Header { get; set; }
    [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
    public ITemplate Body { get; set; }
    [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
    public ITemplate Footer { get; set; }
}
```

This is how it is formatted in the aspx/ascx file:

```xml
<cc1:Lightbox ID="LightBox1" runat="server">
    <Header>Header HTML</Header>
    <Body>Body HTML</Body>
    <Footer>Footer HTML</Footer>
</cc1:Lightbox>
```

If a section exists, then the `CreateChildControls()` method wraps it in a div tag with certain classes.  It ends up like this, but more complicated:

```xml
<div class="header">
    <div class="title">Header HTML</div>
</div>
<div class="body">Body HTML</div>
<div class="footer">Footer HTML</div>
```

I don't know of a good way to do something like this in Razor.  I could turn it into one or more helper methods.  However, this means I either need pass HTML as strings or convert each ITemplate section to this "fun" format:

```cs
Func<dynamic, object> header = @<text>
    <span id="logo">
        <img src="@path" />
    </span>
</text>;
...
@LightBox(header, body, footer) // This would contain logic from CreateChildControls
```

Is this the best that is possible with Razor?

The only other thing I can think of is placing the HTML as is on the page and using a JavaScript module to then modify the inner sections with new container divs, but I don't see why this work can't stay on the server side.

Comment: Why do you  continue to use lightbox?

Comment: @Hadee what do you mean?  This is a WebControl used on 49 pages in this website.

Comment: There are tools to do lightbox functionality better in MVC. like bootstrap modal.

Comment: It isn't an actual lightbox.  It kind of look likes one, though.  I have no idea why it is named that.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach for you is using jQuery. In jquery you could use something like `$( "p" ).addClass( "myClass yourClass" );`. 
If there is "p", it will add related class on that, if not, nothing will happen.
Another option is replacing other controls with lightbox, like bootstrap modal.